# "Docker is not supported on this Mac"

Tags: docker, installation, dockerfile

I have previously run Docker on my Mac uninstalled it and tried to install it again and am getting this stranger error: "You can't open the application because 'Docker' is not supported on this Mac".

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKxyK.png)

Answer (score 18):

I had this error as well, and then I realized that I downloaded the wrong installation file. On the Docker site, there are two options - 'Mac with Intel Chip' or 'Mac with Apple Chip'. I have an Intel Chip and found that I accidentally downloaded the Apple Chip version. The Intel Chip version worked fine for me.

Comment: I am glad I'm not the only one who made an easy mistake. Thank you!

Comment: i think Docker have this wrong on their Getting Started page - as that showed the error above. I downloaded it from here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/#mac-with-intel-chip and had more luck!

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful while selecting binary i.e

**"IntelChip" vs "Applechip"**.

https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/

[image]